# How does sizeof operator behaves in below code snippet?

Tags: c, sizeof

Please explain the OP for below code snippet :

```
int *a="";
char *b=NULL;
float *c='\0' ; 
printf(" %d",sizeof(a[1])); // prints 4 
printf(" %d",sizeof(b[1])); // prints 1
printf(" %d",sizeof(c[1])); // prints 4
```

Compiler interprets a[1] as *(a+1) , so a has some address , now it steps 4 bytes ahead , then it will have some garbage value there so how is the OP 4 bytes , even if I do a[0] , still it prints 4 , although it is an empty string , so how come its size is 4 bytes ?

Here we are finding out the size of the variable the pointer is pointing to , so if I say size of a[1] , it means size of *(a+1), Now a has the address of a string constant which is an empty string , after I do +1 to that address it moves 4 bytes ahead , now its at some new address , now how do we know the size of this value , it can be an integer , a character or a float , anything , so how to reach to a conclusion for this ?

Comment: What compiler are you using that lets any of that compile?

Comment: @Mysticial Any `c` compiler? http://ideone.com/p9PyKX

Comment: The `sizeof` operator works actually on type not on the value of an expression. Thus, it returns the correct result without even access the value (which otherwise might have caused a crash).

Comment: I am using GCC-4.9.2

Comment: To prove that I am correct you may try any value in the brackets... (Even negative values should work.)

Comment: The proper format for `sizeof`'s `size_t`-typed result is `%zu`. Using the wrong format gives you undefined behavior.

Comment: `sizeof(a[1]) == sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(b[1]) == sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(c[1]) == sizeof(float)`

Comment: @Scheff Not totally true, there's variable-length arrays too. Those have to have `sizeof` evaluate at runtime.

Comment: @unwind Interesting thought. (Transfering the sample problem to dynamic arrays: a pointer to a dynamic array accessed with brackets. This makes me dizzy...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sizeof operator does not evaluate its operand except one case.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer.
>   **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
>   result is an integer constant**.

In this code snippet

```
int *a="";
char *b=NULL;
float *c='\0' ; 
printf(" %d",sizeof(a[1])); // prints 4 
printf(" %d",sizeof(b[1])); // prints 1
printf(" %d",sizeof(c[1])); // prints 4
```

the type of the expression `a[1]` is `int`, the type of the expression `b[1]` is `char` and the type of the expression `c[1]` is `float`.

So the `printf` calls output correspondingly `4`, `1`, `4`.

However the format specifiers in the calls are specified incorrectly. Instead of `"%d"` there must be `"%zu"` because the type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is `size_t`.

From the same section of the C Standard

> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-deﬁned,
>   and **its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t**, deﬁned in
>   `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

Comment: I found [sizeof in cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) which states return type `size_t` (would have been my first guess also). Interesting that the cited standard says: _The result is an integer._ Is the actual "return type of `sizeof`" mentioned somewhere else?

Comment: @Scheff See my appended post.

Comment: @Scheff You are a kind person.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , Can you please explain how is a[1] an int ? If I try printing the value of a[1] ,b[1] , c[1] , it is gives runtime error .

Comment: @stackuser You declared three pointers. The expression with the subscript operator applied to a pointer has the pointed type. Thus for example if you write int *a; then the expression a[1] has type int. As I wrote in the answer expressions in the sizeof operator are not evaluated except when the operand is a variable length array and are known at compile time. Outside the sizeof operator the expressions you are using are invalid and have undefined behavior.

Comment: so at compile time a[1] is not evaluated right , the compiler just sees the type of pointer and prints the size right ?

Comment: @stackuser You are right. The compiler just determines the type of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

This is all done statically, i.e. no dereferencing is happening at runtime. This is how the `sizeof` operator works, unless you use variable-length arrays (VLAs), then it must do work at runtime.

Which is why you can get away with `sizeof`:ing through a `NULL` pointer, and other things.

You should still be getting trouble for

```
int *a = "";
```

which makes no sense. I really dislike the `c` initializer too, but at least that makes sense.

Comment: Makes no sense to humans, but to the computer a char to float* is implicit and makes plenty of sense.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox it's a pointer to `float`, so what really happens is `float * c = '\0' == 0 => NULL;` though it's a confusing way to assign a `NULL`.

Comment: @Kninnug Yeah, I was over-reacting a bit regarding `c`, changed.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` operator happens at compilation (except for VLA's). It is looking at the type of an expression, not the actual data so even something like this will work:

```
sizeof(((float *)NULL)[1])
```

and give you the size of a float. Which on your system is 4 bytes.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ljo81S)

Even though this looks super bad, it is all well defined, since no dereference ever actually occurs. This is all operations on type information at compile time.

Comment: Not totally true, there are variable-length arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` is based on the data type, so whilst it's getting the sizes outside the bounds of memory allocated to your variables, it doesn't matter as it's worked out at compile time rather than run time.

Comment: It's not a function, the parentheses are not part of the operator's name.